# How to hide borders created by WS_SIZEBOX using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I create custom panels (TMyPanel) with runtime resizing feature. Is there any way to hide the borders without losing the resizing feature?

```
type
  TMyPanel = class(TPanel)
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

...

procedure TMyPanel.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.Style := Params.Style or WS_SIZEBOX;
end;

...

var
  MyPanel1: TMyPanel;
begin
  MyPanel1:=TMyPanel.Create(self);
  MyPanel1.Parent:=self;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: So, is your question how to make your panels sizeable without adding borders, or is it how to hide the borders when the `WS_SIZEBOX` style is included.

Comment: Override `WM_NCHITTEST` to tell the system where your resize "borders" are, in absence of `WS_SIZEBOX`.

Comment: Probably by (not) drawing the non-client area yourself. It may adversely effect resize-ability though. Pretty counter-intuitive.. WS_SIZEBOX is more commonly known as WS_THICKFRAME, those frames serve as a visual clue about what they are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see from your question, you want to achieve resing of `TPanel` even if has no non-client borders. If I got you right I can share with you one of solution. For some of my control I used this technique and it works.
Indeed, `WS_SIZEBOX` style is not needed here.

```
unit PanelEx;

interface

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  ExtCtrls;

type
  TPanelEx = class(TPanel)
  protected
    procedure WMNCHITTEST(var Message: TMessage); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  end;


implementation


procedure TPanelEx.WMNCHITTEST(var Message: TMessage);
const
  BorderSize = 10;
var
  P: TPoint;
begin
  Inherited;

  if not Assigned(Parent) then
    Exit;

  P.X := LOWORD(Message.LParam);
  P.Y := HIWORD(Message.LParam);

  // Convert screen coordinates into client
  P := Parent.ScreenToClient(P);

  // Decide what result message should have
  if (Abs(Left + Width - P.X) < BorderSize) and (Abs(Top + Height - P.Y) < BorderSize) then
    Message.Result := HTBOTTOMRIGHT
  else
  if (Abs(Left - P.X) < BorderSize) and (Abs(Top + Height - P.Y) < BorderSize) then
    Message.Result := HTBOTTOMLEFT
  else
  if (Abs(Left + Width - P.X) < BorderSize) and (Abs(Top - P.Y) < BorderSize) then
    Message.Result := HTTOPRIGHT
  else
  if (Abs(Left - P.X) < BorderSize) and (Abs(Top - P.Y) < BorderSize) then
    Message.Result := HTTOPLEFT
  else
  if Abs(Left - P.X) < BorderSize then
    Message.Result := HTLEFT
  else
  if Abs(Top - P.Y) < BorderSize then
    Message.Result := HTTOP
  else
  if Abs(Left + Width - P.X) < BorderSize then
    Message.Result := HTRIGHT
  else
  if Abs(Top + Height - P.Y) < BorderSize then
    Message.Result := HTBOTTOM;
end;


end.
```

Comment: That code can never end up with "`HTTOPRIGHT`" (f.ex.), as the `(Abs(Top - P.Y) < BorderSize)` is detected as "`HTTOP`". You should test for the diagonals before testing for the linear ones.

Comment: @HeartWare thank you - it is my silly mistake. I took that code from one of my project and also deleted additional code I use in this message handler, that is why I made a sad mistake.

Comment: Thank you Dima. This is brilliant.